# Choosing GUI framework for portlets under WebCenter portal

Tags: portlet, webcenter

I'm just looking through available technologies to create portlets using WSRP. So we have the following requirements (I'll try to explain so as I can):

- backend part: Jax-WS webservices implementation (in fact JPA + some business logic)
- frontend: portlets should use Jax-WS webservices and should be exposed through WSRP and consumed in Oracle WebCenter portal
- everything should be built via Maven

I'm having troubles with selecting a proper framework for portlet development. 
A couple of things which I'm considering:

- ADF - has a big learning curve, tightly coupled to Oracle stack, I wouldn't like to use it
- Vaadin framework - looks fine, but its latest version doesn't support WSRP Add on, so I will have to write something on my own

There are also a couple of others possible frameworks which I have not looked through yet: JSF, Spring Portlet MVC.

Maybe somebody of you has already used similar stack and can give some advice on which framework is more convenient for portlet with WSRP. I would very much appreciate any thoughts on that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For me I used JSF with JSF-Portlet-Bridge, Struts and ADF
But I always preferred ADF since it gave me a quick way to generate WSRP portlets from Task-Flows.

If you are going to develop big list of Portlets, I'd tell you to consider ADF, even though the learning curve might be steep but it'll be worth it, and you already have knowledge in JSF it'll be an easy task!

Comment: Well, I have some experience with ADF, but the components there are very heavy, not customizable in fact. If you want to build even a simple table - it may be difficult(maybe pure ADF without portlets is fine, but when it comes to portlets and consuming them in portal - believe me, it is too complicated).

Comment: You can use JSF components if you think ADF components are heavy, but still you can get the benefit of converting Task Flows to WSRP portlets with 2-clicks using JDeveloper

Comment: do u know if there are any limitations on JSF's particular version to be compliant with WSRP? Maybe you can give a link to some example in the web? Also we would like not to use JDeveloper at all or maybe just use it for some minor things.

Comment: Yes, I believe it only supports JSF1.2, here is a link to give you step by step how to do it http://andrejusb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/producing-jsr-168-portlets-directly.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. JSF1.2 is not that good as JSF2.2, and I would like to get rid of JDeveloper. I'm thinking about writing my own WSRP Add on for Vaadin 7. We'll see if I could make it. If not then I have to go with ADF or JSF :-(

Comment: I'd be interested in the Vaadin option, just open-source the project and give me the url :)